# Error creating bean with name while using @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, selenium-webdriver

```
[2017-03-22 15:01:56:301] [main] ERROR TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@d6da883] to prepare test instance [com.fisc.testcases.login.SSLoginSuccess@80ec1f8]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.fisc.testcases.login.SSLoginSuccess': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.fisc.config.ServiceConfig com.fisc.testcases.login.SSLoginSuccess.config; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fisc.config.ServiceConfig] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
```

My SSLoginSuccess

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fisc.config")
public class SSLoginSuccess extends AbstractBase {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SSLoginSuccess.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConfig config;

    /*@Autowired
    public void SelfServiceConfig(SelfServiceConfig config){
        this.config = config;
    }*/

    //private WebDriver d1;

    @BeforeTest
    private void openSSLoginPage() throws IOException {
        // Launch the Internet Explorer and get the SS Login page
        //d1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get(GlobalConstant.SELFSERVICE_URL);
    }

    @AfterTest
    private void closeBrowser() throws IOException {
        // Launch the Internet Explorer and get the SS Login page
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.close();
            driver = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify Successful Login with correct user id and password
     *
     */
    @Test
    public void test_successful_login() throws IOException {

        LOGGER.info(" Verify Successful Login with correct userid and password ");
```

ServiceConfig

```
public abstract class ServiceConfig {

    private Map<String, String> config;

    private ConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();

    public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
        return conversionService.convert(config.get(key), type);

    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return get(key, String.class);

    }

    public Map<String, String> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Map<String, String> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not autowire an Abstract class

Comment: Abstract class can not be autowire. You need to create another class which extends your abstract class and after that your autowire should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot autowire an Abstract class
2. The class needs to be meta-annotated with @Component to be picked up by a component scan in order to be autowired.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing @Component annotation on that ServiceConfig and spring cannot find any class to map to your autowired property. Also, it is not good practice to wire fields, you can better wire setter.(If you try in idea to wire spring field inspection will tell you that spring developers do not recommend wiring fields.)